# Sitefinity Kendo syncReady problems

Tags: kendo-ui, sitefinity

I want to use the MVC Kendo's controls like `@Html.Kendo().TextBox()` and `@(Html.Kendo().Grid` in my Sitefinity view. In the view I have added `ScriptRef.JQuery` and `ScriptRef.KendoWeb` as well as the StyleSheet's. In the ASP.NET MVC R3 2020 sample project I have used the DLL file Kendo.Mvc.dll wrappers as a reference in the Sitefinity. But when I run the application I am getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: kendo.syncReady is not a function at Preview:1160`. Any help with code defined steps would very appreciated.

wrappers path reference in the Sitefinity

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik UI for ASP.NET MVC R3 2020\wrappers\aspnetmvc\Examples\MVC5\Kendo.Mvc.Examples\bin
```

view

```
@using Kendo.Mvc.UI
@Html.Script(ScriptRef.JQuery, "head", true)
@Html.Script(ScriptRef.KendoWeb, "head", true)


@Html.Section("jquery")
@Html.Section("kendo")

@Html.StyleSheet(Url.EmbeddedResource("Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.Reference", "Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.Scripts.Kendo.styles.kendo_common_min.css"), sectionName: "head", throwException: false)

@Html.StyleSheet(Url.EmbeddedResource("Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.Reference", "Telerik.Sitefinity.Resources.Scripts.Kendo.styles.kendo_bootstrap_min.css"), sectionName: "bottom", throwException: false)





@Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("customSearch")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a widget view or a page template view?

If a widget view, you better remove these 2 sections:

```
@Html.Section("jquery")
@Html.Section("kendo")
```

Also, make sure your page view has a section called "head"

To prevent this error, you need to make sure that your kendo init code:

```
@Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("customSearch")
```

is placed **after** the kendo/jquery js scripts.

Just inspect the source of your page and make sure the above is correct.

Comment: What do you mean widget view or a page template view?

Comment: Page template view is the one under your resource package / mvc / views / layouts. Widget templates are those under /Mvc/Views

Comment: Ok so it’s the widget view I will remove the lines